# One hour missing from jquery datetime picker because of Daylight Savings Time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery datetime picker but it when I select 27th March 2022, 2 AM is missing, because it doesn't exist in our timezone because of the DST change, is there a way to force CET timezone instead (to have 3 AM missing instead of 2 AM)? or can I have all the hours displayed irrespective of the timezone hour changes?

This is the code I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I understand that this happens because the script runs client-side and gets the local time, but I need to force CET time instead or force all the hours to be displayed, thanks.

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using?  There might be an option to set the UI timezone.

Comment: I'm using jquery, https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: ... which doesn't have a timepicker component...

Comment: apologies. https://getdatepicker.com/4/